# excel filter rows by group

Tags: excel, filter, group

How can we filter the following table, but grouped by project?
So, my expectation is to add a filter, So that when I select Project A, all tasks in it will appear.
[image]

Comment: Either fix your data to include the project ID on every row,ir add a helper column to do that

Answer (score 2):

It looks like somebody is in need of something neat :-)
Press <kbd>Ctrl+G</kbd>, "Special", "Current region" and then <kbd>Ctrl+G</kbd>, "Special", "Blanks", for selecting all the blanks in your region, you'll get something like this:

[image]

As you see, all blanks are selected, and the top left has the focus (cell "A3" in my case). Inside that, you want to have the value of the cell just above (cell "A2" in my case), so you click inside the formula bar and you type there: `=A2` and your press <kbd>**CTRL**+ENTER</kbd> (don't forget to press the "Control" button), and you'll get such a result:

[image]

From that, you can start filtering
Have fun :-)

Comment: I wanted to Not repeat Ref and Project names, so that it looks tidy  :) But this helped

Comment: @Ram For appearance, you can use `Conditional Formatting` to blank the duplicated project names (by setting the font color to the same color as the interior color).

Comment: Thank you @RonRosenfeld - The Conditional Formatting, - "Use a formula to determine which cells to format" method to hide trailing cells with font colour same as fill colour if both cells are equal